# Decrypt mpeg dash live streaming with Widevine decryption url and restream with ffmpeg

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg

I have

1. MPD file by URL (Video URL) - Stream type DASH
2. Widevine License URL - https: // drm .... /widevine/cenc/..../getlicense

This bunch can be opened using an online player and view the entire mpd file

I want open this video url and restream it with ffmpeg

Is there any ffmpeg command to do that?